# Python Application Error on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter, google-cloud-storage, bots

i created twitter Application on google app engine Using this repository https://github.com/cybermithun/twitter-search-reply-bot while running this app i am getting this Error. can anyone tell me whats wrong with the code

```
Internal Server Error

The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~leoapp109/1.391952730855998659/main.py", line 32, in get
    lastTweet = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM LastTweet").fetch(1)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#**strong text**
# Copyright 2007 Google Inc.

import datetime
from google.appengine.ext import db
import webapp2
import time
import sys
import random
from twython import Twython, TwythonError
from google.appengine.ext import db

class LastTweet(db.Model):
    tweetId = db.StringProperty()

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        idnum = 0
        lastTweet = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM LastTweet").fetch(1)[0]

#        try:
#            lastTweet = LastTweet.all()
#        except:
#            lastTweet = None
#        if lastTweet != None:
#            idnum = lastTweet.tweetId
#        else:
#            idnum = "0"


        apiKey = 'QQQ'
        apiSecret = 'QQQ'
        accessToken = 'QQQ'
        accessTokenSecret = 'QQQ'
        twitter = Twython(apiKey,apiSecret,accessToken,accessTokenSecret)
        message = "Hi, if you Love Wine you will Love to Wear this Wine T-Shirt www.teespring.com/WineT"
        search_results = twitter.search(q="#Winelover", since_id = idnum, count=20)
        print(search_results)
        for tweet in search_results["statuses"]:
            screenname = "@" + tweet["user"]["screen_name"]+" ";
            print tweet["id_str"]
            try:
                #self.response.write('Hello world!')
                twitter.update_status(status=screenname + message, in_reply_to_status_id=tweet["id_str"])
            except TwythonError:
                pass
            idnum = tweet["id_str"]
            print(idnum)
        if search_results:
            lastTweet.tweetId = idnum
            lastTweet.put()

       # self.response.write('Hello world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Looks like your fetch is returning an empty container.

Answer (score 1):

The last line of the traceback identifies the line of code causing the problem:

```
lastTweet = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM LastTweet").fetch(1)[0]
```

and tells us what the problem is:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Your code expects to the result of `db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM LastTweet").fetch(1)` to be a `list`, and is assigning the first element of that list - the element at index 0 - to `lastTweet`.  However the list is empty so there is no element at index 0 and so you get an `IndexError`.

To fix this you need to either wrap the code in a try / except block to handle the exception

```
try:
    lastTweet = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM LastTweet").fetch(1)[0]
except IndexError:
    lastTweet = None # or whatever
```

Or if you are only fetching a single tweet, as seems to be the case, call the query's `get` method to retrieve the tweet or None:

```
lastTweet = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM LastTweet").get()
if lastTweet:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: hey thanks for answering my question i tried your code its not working , i have included my code above can check it.